# When will SuperCam examine its first target?

Tags: mars, rovers, perseverance

The Perseverance rover just landed yesterday. I'm guessing that there first are some checks to do on the rover itself before it starts to do any science, so the science instruments like SuperCam might not be used right away. When is SuperCam scheduled to be used for the first time?

Answer (score 2):

From this [NASA press release](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/perseverance-rover-s-supercam-science-instrument-delivers-first-results), SuperCam got its first readings on March 9, two and a half weeks after its landing on the red planet.